# Element in html gets updated but returns value only after an "alert" statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, window, mathjax

I call a child window from a parent window. The child window updates a textarea in the parent window.
I can see that the textarea is updated visually. But when I try to get the value of the textarea into a string, it returns only the previous value.
It returns the current string only if I place an alert before getting the value.
Is this a problem of refreshing?  Kindly guide.

**Parent Window Code**

```
  window.selectedVal = "";
 window.open("http://www.build-exam.com/mathform.html","Math",'width=900,height=500,scrollbars=yes');
 document.getElementById("btn_save").click();
```

**Child Window Code**

```
btn_ret.onclick = function() 
{
 window.opener.document.getElementById("testbox2").value = s_ques;
 window.close();
}
```

**Parent window btn click code**

```
btn_save.onclick = function() 
{ 
var ss_ques;

//alert("came here");
ss_ques = document.getElementById("testbox2").value;
}
```

The variable ss_ques gets the current value only if the alert("came here") is uncommented

Also, please note there is code for rendering MathJax further.  Is it because of MathJax?

Answer (score 1):

**Parent window btn click code**

```
btn_save.onclick = function() 
{ 
var ss_ques;

//alert("came here");
ss_ques = document.getElementById("testbox2").value;

localStorage.setItem("ss_ques", ss_ques);
}
```

**Child Window Code**

```
btn_ret.onclick = function() 
{
 window.opener.document.getElementById("testbox2").value = localStorage.getItem("ss_ques");
 window.close();
}
```

Comment: In child window code, the variable is s_ques (not ss_ques). I want to set the contents of s_ques from child window into parent element testbox2

Comment: I also tried using localStorage. It still doesn't work unless an alert is placed.